# How to print user input array in one line

Tags: c

Trying to print out the user input of the array online but ended up in prints in one element at a time.

The following code aims to compute the sum of elements in the n number of ArrayList:

```
// let int count be counter
int count=0;
int inputNum;

// calculate the length of the array
int len;

for (int i=0; i<numOfLines; i++)
{
    count++;
    printf("Enter line %d: \n", count);

    for (int j=0; j<numOfLines; j++)
    {
        scanf("%d", &inputNum);
        printf("DEBUG:input number %d \n", inputNum++);
        if (inputNum != 0)
        {
            int arrNum[]= {inputNum++};
            len = sizeof(arrNum)/sizeof(arrNum[0]);
            printf("Total: %d \n", len);
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Enter number of lines:
2

Enter line 1:

3 2 3 4

DEBUG:input number 3

Total: 1

DEBUG:input number 2

Total: 1

Enter line 2:

DEBUG:input number 3

Total: 1

DEBUG:input number 4

Total: 1
```

Correct sample output:

```
Enter number of lines:

2

Enter line 1:

3 2 3 4

Total: 9

Enter line 2:

4 1 2 3 4

Total: 10
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems the first number of each line is the number of data in that line. Use that information.

```
// let int count be counter
int count=0;
int inputNum;

for (int i=0; i<numOfLines; i++)
{
    count++;
    printf("Enter line %d: \n", count);

    int sum = 0;
    scanf("%d", &inputNum);
    for (int j=0; j<inputNum; j++)
    {
        int value;
        scanf("%d", &value);
        printf("DEBUG:input number %d \n", value);
        sum += value;
    }

    if (inputNum != 0)
    {
        printf("Total: %d \n", sum);
    }

}
```